# Can I describe an arbitrary graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

This is, I think, a fairly simple question, but I haven't been able to find an answer to. Is there any graph for which there's no way to describe it in terms of a polynomial, function, or any other formula? If so, why?

Comment: You can always define a function $f$ of two variables, such that $f(x,y)=1$ if the point $(x,y)$ is on the graph, and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can draw (any) arbitrary curve that represents a function, but measuring what that function is exactly (with infinite precision) from the drawing is an insurmountable task.

Comment: Can we simply use b-splines or Fourier series with infinite terms to describe potentially any drawings?

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER the problem of keeping track of infinite number of coefficients exceeds the space available for computation

Comment: this makes lots of sense.